# cannot set property onclick of null

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

I am goofing around with some plain vanilla JS today and have a question about the onclick event.

Might be best to just show the code:

```
function _(x) {
    return document.querySelector(x);
}
function toggleSlide(el, maxH) {
    var target = _(el);
    if(target.style.height == null || target.style.height == maxH+"px") {
        target.style.transition = "height 0.3s linear 0s";
        target.style.height = "0px";
    }else {
        target.style.transition = "height 0.3s linear 0s";
        target.style.height = maxH+"px";
    }
}
```

Everything works if I add the onclick event to the button like:

```
<button id="menu-btn" onclick="toggleSlide('#menu', 280)">Toggle</button>
```

But I get the error,

> "connot set property 'onclick' of null"

When I try like this:

```
_('#menu-btn').onclick = function() {
    toggleSlide('#menu', 280)
}
```

How can I access my toggle function without adding the **onclick** in the html?

Comment: I think if you debug this with firebug or something similar, it will probably give you the answer. Does your js run onload?

Comment: You shouldn't be having this error if your script is included right before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add the listener before the button exists. Either put the problematic code in a separate `<script>` after the button or in an `onload` (preferred, see code below).

```
window.onload = function() {
    _("#menu").onclick = function() {
        toggleSlide('#menu', 280);
    };
};
```

**EDIT:** Note that if you have multiple of these they should be put in the same `onload` function, or the last one will override the ones before.